# Redux toolkit persisting data in session storage?

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, session-storage, redux-persist

I have used redux toolkit for state managament and i am also persisting the state in redux persist but i want to store it in session storage? How can i do that avoiding local storage to persist data?

Comment: Data in `sessionStorage` is cleared when the page session ends. You need `localStorage` to persist data between sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these [storage engines](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#storage-engines). You should use `storageSession` provides by `redux-persist`.

- `sessionStorage` - `import storageSession from 'redux-persist/lib/storage/session'`

Answer (score 0):

After you install `reduxjs-toolkit-persist` module, above issue will fixed.

```
npm i reduxjs-toolkit-persist

import storageSession from "reduxjs-toolkit-persist/lib/storage/session";
```

I hope this will help you as well.
Thank you.
Best Regards.